# Possible to redirect file to a console program as if the user typed the content?

Tags: linux, console, redirect, black-box-testing

I have a C program which uses a scanf to read a number and then prints the number. I want somehow to simulate the keystrokes by redirecting a file so I can make a bash script that is supposed to do black-box-testing.

This is my program(*prog*):

```
int main(){
    int a;

    printf("Write a number: ", a);
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nYou entered: %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I then have a file(*infile*) with this content:

```
12\n
```

Is it possible somehow to redirect the file as input to the program to simulate user input?

When typing

```
./prog < infile
```

I get

```
Write a number: 
You entered: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file content must be this:

```
12
```

Without **\n**

I tried your program and it works!

```
echo '12' | ./prog
```

Comment: Only problem is that I don't want to use a pipe but a file. :P

Comment: As I wrote, I tried with **./prog < infile** and it worked. Be sure your file does not contain '\n' and it works! Reading from a file or piping is similar. You can try with **cat infile | ./prog**

Comment: seems that my problem was that I had a file with similar name in the same folder and I was using that instead(dumb me). Thanks for the answer anyway!